# Why does RadioButton.IsChecked return Nullable<bool> rather than regular bool?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a C# WPF application with a few RadioButtons. When I want to check if a RadioButton is selected, I have to use:

```
if(myRadioButton.IsChecked == true)
{
    //Code
}
```

If I use:

```
if(myRadioButton.IsChecked)
{
    //Code
}
```

It throws an error saying:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'.
```

Why does the `IsChecked` property return bool? instead of bool when it's value can only possibly be true or false?

Comment: Because before user interaction a `RadioButton` has a null value

Comment: @WaqasRaja I'm guessing you haven't checked before commenting.

Comment: @hvd, if it stores null then it means it is nullable